# Customview with bottom round corners not getting shadow effect in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiview

I am showing some customview. I am trying to show only bottom corners with bottom shadow. It is able to getting bottom round corners, but shadow effect not coming. If I remove corners, then shadow effect is coming.

```
func showCustomView() {
    self.customview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
    self.customview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    self.customview.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    self.customview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.customview.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 12)
}

    extension UIView {
        
        func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
            
            if #available(iOS 11, *) {
                self.clipsToBounds = true
                self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
                var masked = CACornerMask()
                if corners.contains(.topLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
                if corners.contains(.topRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
                if corners.contains(.bottomLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
                if corners.contains(.bottomRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
                self.layer.maskedCorners = masked
            }
            else {
                let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
                let mask = CAShapeLayer()
                mask.path = path.cgPath
                layer.mask = mask
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: self.clipsToBounds = false (false is default so removing the line works as well)

Comment: Tried, but no effect, still shadow not showing @DanielMarx

Comment: weird, copy pasted your code and works fine for me. where do you call showCustomView()

Comment: override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self. showCustomView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self. showCustomView()
    } here I am calling

Comment: Already in this         func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
 function I have set it true only, but still shadow not coming for bottom

Comment: just to be on the same side: you tried removing `self.clipsToBounds = true` from you custom extension `roundCorners(...)`?

Comment: Now working, Thanks @DanielMarx

Comment: You can post this in answer, I can accept and upvote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `self.clipsToBounds = true`
from `roundCorners(...)`

**Example**

```
import UIKit

class MissingShadowViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        showCustomView()
    }
    
    func showCustomView() {
        self.customView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        self.customView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.customView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        self.customView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.customView.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 12)
    }

}

extension UIView {
    
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            // clipping here will hide shadows
            // self.clipsToBounds = true
            self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
            var masked = CACornerMask()
            if corners.contains(.topLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.topRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.bottomLeft) { masked.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
            if corners.contains(.bottomRight) { masked.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
            self.layer.maskedCorners = masked
        }
        else {
            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            layer.mask = mask
        }
    }
}
```